# How to use Pandas DF values as string in Python so i can sendkeys in Selenium with the exact valeu extracted from Pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, stock

So i have a csv file with stock Symbol and prices. I created a webscraper to interact with my 'Home-Broker' because i dont know how to handle websockets yet.

What i want to do, is to use Pandas to get a Symbol and a Price from the csv file and use selenium to .sendkeys with the Symbol and price on each specific form.

Bellow is the example of the output of df.head(3) from my csv.

```
      Symbol   Price
    0  APPL    319.61
    1  GOOG    1,508.79
    2  AMZN    2,150.80
```

And here is the input i am using to sendkeys on my home-broker, which i am manually changing on the code for each stock.

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys('APPL')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAssElet_ORDERS1"]').send_keys('319.61')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DV_barraCompraVende_BOOK1"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]').click()
time.sleep(10)
```

I need to substitute the .send_keys('APPL') & .send_keys('319.61') to some sort of .send_keys df.head(0) and loop ultil i send a buy order for the df.head(3)

Is there any way to do this?

I appreciate your patience and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your DataFrame as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Symbol","Price"], data=[["APPL",319.61],["GOOG",1508.79],["AMZN",2150.80]])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index)
    print(row['Symbol'])
    print(row['Price'])
```

There are faster ways but since you are already bottlenecked by the selenium operations it doesn't really matter.

So in your case use:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys(row['Symbol'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAssElet_ORDERS1"]').send_keys(row['Price'])
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DV_barraCompraVende_BOOK1"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]').click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I would also not use SendKeys if possible. Try to see if you can set the value directly.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is a really nice answer! If i may ask, what are those faster ways to do this kind of work, so i can learn more about those and emprove my skills? Thank you.

Comment: If the home-broker site is using an API, using that would mean that you could dump selenium all together. I understand that it might not be the case. But in any case look and see if you could implement the same logic for the home-broker site with [the requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
Symbols = df['Symbol'].tolist()
Prices = df['Price'].tolist()
for Symbol,Price in zip (Symbols,Prices):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys(Symbol)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAtivo_BOOK1"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtAssElet_ORDERS1"]').send_keys(Price)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DV_barraCompraVende_BOOK1"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]').click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Your answer is really good, i will try to adapt it in my code! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to grab stock prices, you can do it like this.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold


start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()


################################
### OR...for a different layout...

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()
```

Comment: what is the source which this code gets the prices from? And can you tell me what does the rest of the code does?

Comment: Just run the code and you will see what it does.  Copy/paste, select the relevant portion of code, and hot the F9 key.  That's it.

Comment: People told me i shouldn't run random code from people without understanding it. I ignored what people told me, and run your code. It got me a FutureWarning for pandas.util.testing is deprecated and Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: where should the output be?

Comment: Take a look at this when you have some free time.
https://readthedocs.org/projects/pandas-datareader/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: Very useful trick you just told me! Thanks ash! Can you disclose what does the rest of the code does? I mean by numpy, pylab, sklearn... I am really curious!

Comment: Oh, yes, those are libraries for many different things.  That's just the first part of the code that I was using for some portfolio management tasks.  If all you are doing is importing data, all you need is the code I shared with you, as well as pandas and pandas_datareader.  If you want to learn more, see this: https://towardsdatascience.com/efficient-frontier-portfolio-optimisation-in-python-e7844051e7f

Comment: This is good too: https://pythonforfinance.net/2017/01/21/investment-portfolio-optimisation-with-python/